# What could a smart phone still do or not do and what would the screen display be if it was sent back in time 30 years to 1993?

Tags: technology, time-travel

A person is sent back in time 30 years to 1993 and they still have their phone. The phone is an iphone 11. It is on a contract. The battery is fully charged. The phone has a number of apps on it including the most popular social media apps and some local apps such as a step counter, camera, voice recorder. The person does not have a charger. They do not have access to a modem. They are in a very remote area but can travel to a large city (eg London).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145429/discussion-on-question-by-avengingearth-what-could-a-smart-phone-still-do-or-not); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The phone would look exactly like it would if the phone did not have cell service today. (..... No Service), link below: https://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+screen+no+service&sxsrf=APwXEdd_96A3Z6Y8GeSmV2t_mcIrBeMWnA:1681936008991&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiV4Oby47b-AhVpEFkFHVcdDlUQ0pQJegQIAxAC&biw=1920&bih=937&dpr=1#imgrc=krCLzKMB9hVNaM

Comment: To expand on @DevelopingDeveloper's comment, assuming you're talking about a UK-based mobile phone (you mentioned London) your immediate problem with using it as a phone is that it wouldn't have a recognizeable number; [all UK mobile numbers changed in 1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhONEday) so the number on your modern phone wouldn't be recognized by any network,

Comment: You realize the processor alone on this outclasses the fastest supercomputer in existence in 1993

Comment: @lupe - Without a charger, it won't be doing that for long.

Comment: Oh, sure, but that's not the worst problem to solve

Comment: @lupe and you can't use any of it because it's an iPhone which is not allowed to run any programs except the ones you got from the app store. Isn't capitalism great?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**”What would the screen display be”**

I’m going to assume you’re asking here about what would the display show on your phone, as in the OS it would display.  If that’s the case, it would be the last version of iOS that the phone was updated to.  (It’s important to note here that you won’t be able to update the phone OS version while you’re back in time, because obviously iOS doesn’t even exist yet).  Any files stored on the phone’s built-in storage should still be accessible, and things that don’t require internet like the camera app, calculator, clock, etc. should definitely still work.  I’m going to say that Social Media apps will likely not work, because all of the infrastructure they use hasn’t even been invented yet, so there’s no server host for the app to contact.  It would still show the app, but it would likely give you an error message something like “failed to connect to server” for trying to use any functionality that uses internet connection.  For a good real-world test for how the phone would function, assuming you have an iPhone since you include a specific model type, test its functionality with Airplane Mode on.  Make sure that both Cellular and WiFi are toggled off (you can do this in control center by toggling on Airplane Mode, though I like to also toggle off Wifi and Cellular in Control Center as well).  If you try this, it will give you a very accurate idea of what your character would be able to do.

**“The Person does not have a charger”**

Just to clarify, they can’t get a charger no matter what city they go to.  The lightning cord that the iPhone 11 uses for charging has not been invented yet.  Neither has QI wireless charging.  So your person will not be able to recharge this phone.  Now, if they have a bit of electrical skill, they could possibly make a wireless charger for the phone, or possibly even a plug, but the wireless charger would actually be far simpler mechanically to build provided the character has the knowledge required.  Alternatively, maybe a tech savvy person from that time period could make a wireless charger or charging cord for it provided they know some basic things like voltage and amperage limits.

I hope this helps you out!  If you have any other questions related to this, feel free to comment and ask, and I can try to provide more ideas and info.

Comment: Thank you. That's very useful. I am still unsure if the phone could make a call to emergency services given the iphone 11 supports GSM. It of course is unable to under flight mode conditions.

Comment: @AvengingEarth  Based on my research I think it could work.  GSM was rolled out late 80’s early 90’s, and by 1993, 2G was common GSM standard.  Modern phones like the iPhone 11 that support LTE can fall back on 2G networks when that’s the only service available.  (There are still some rural areas in Europe and third-world countries where 2G is the only available signal).  This would imply that it could actually possibly work for Emergency Calls, though I don’t think you’d be able to use data because you wouldn’t be recognized by a cell service provider.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2G

Comment: @AvengingEarth I’m glad you found my answer to be useful! . As I said in the other comment, I think emergency calls via 2G could possibly work, but likely nothing else like texting.  Another thing I should look into is whether WiFi existed yet, which I’m pretty sure is a no.  Maybe with a wired Ethernet adapter though?  I can look further into that aspect as well.  But I think for now it’s quite possible Emergency Calls could be supported, though I think that functionality is limited to emergency numbers like 911, though I could be mistaken.

Comment: @AvengingEarth One thing I should note about internet connection is that you’d be limited to what was available in 1993.  None of the apps that use internet would work just because you found a way to connect to the internet, because none of the infrastructure for those apps exists yet.  But you may be able to use your web browser to access old websites that existed at that time?  That’s probably the only functionality you would gain by accessing internet, and even then I’m not sure if modern browsers can read old web code standards that existed back then.

Comment: @KalMadda Modern browsers can: if a webpage doesn't start with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the browser interprets it in "Quirks mode" (i.e., emulating old browser bugs). Anything with Java or Flash is off the table, though; the iPhone was revolutionary in not bothering to implement any of that. Your _bigger_ problem will be the non-existence of Wi-Fi (or even MMS!): there's practically no way to get data onto the phone.

Comment: I suppose you could try to use the microphone and speaker as a dial-up modem… Hell of a lot of code to type into Safari manually, though.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thanks for the clarification there, I wasn’t sure about that part of things.  I wasn’t thinking you’d use wifi because that obviously didn’t exist yet, but maybe a lightning to ethernet adapter would work, though the person would have to take that with them, or someone with the know how and skills would have to make one.

Comment: @KalMadda Pretty sure those are all active; it might be difficult to make. You could do lightning to USB 1, but I don't know whether any software that speaks the Ethernet-over-USB protocol would exist back then.

Comment: The earliest Ethernet-over-USB protocol I can find referenced is [CDC EEM](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/CDC_EEM10.pdf); seems to be 2003 at the earliest. I doubt anything earlier would still be supported by the iPhone 11.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thank you for that info! .

Comment: QI charging requires a wireless "handshake" between the 'phone and charger, which would presumably make the charger far harder to replicate in '93. The handshake is partly a safety feature to stop the charger heating up any metal object that comes within range, so I don't know for sure that a 'phone would refuse to charge from a simple coil, but it seems likely.

Comment: Forget about wireless charging. A simple 5V DC powersupply and connecting it to the 2 leads in the USB plug is all you need for a 200 mA wired charger (takes about 15 hours to fully charge). Add a couple of resistors will get you 1A charging which will be a LOT faster (about 3 hours). Of course you'll do need the schematic so you better have that stored on the phone itself and transfer that to a piece of paper before the battery runs out.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 A potential problem with that is that the iPhone 11, like many modern internet devices, run at least partially on IPv6 which wasn't invented until 1998. While you might be able to jerry-rig an Ethernet-over-USB connector (though it's impossible if you didn't bring a USB-to-Lightning cable with you), I'm not sure what would happen if you tried to connect the iPhone to a modem or router that doesn't even know what IPv6 is.

Comment: I'd want a citation that local emergency numbers were accessible from an otherwise non-authorized phone in the 1990's. Having universally accessible 911 service is (I think) very new and still not fully functional in some places in the USA: "... The FCC set a deadline for 'two-thirds of all cellphone calls to be transmitted to 9-1-1 dispatchers by 2002'... [but] the deadline was pushed back again and again..." https://www.pbs.org/independentlens/blog/history-of-911-americas-emergency-service-before-and-after-kitty-genovese/

Comment: @abion to jerryrig a USB to ethernet you are going to need a usb ethernet device and a rj45 to coax tranciever, since ethernet did not run over twisted pair until later. IPV6 is unnecessary, not all routers know about that even now. However, our next nightmare is that in 1993 we are before CDIR so the device is supposed to assume subnet masks and router addresses from the IP address, which the phone certainly won't do. Its also going to barp on the lack of DHCP. I don't think you can configure static IP on an iphone.

Comment: If the time traveler has brought the needed information they can (with substantial risk) give it to someone with an electronics lab to take it apart and solder directly to the charging port. Or solder directly to the battery terminals. Lithium rechargeable batteries were definitely around by then, though without having the specs for this exact one, they'd want to charge it slowly just in case (better than risking blowing it up). Or they could replace the battery with a different one they know. 3 rechargeable C or D cells would probably work just fine as long as the phone charger was not used.

Comment: If the time traveler has brought the Lightning charging cable then taking it apart and applying 5 volts to the right wires is trivial - provided you remember which ones they are.

Comment: @KalMadda modern browsers should be able to display old static HTML with no problem, however I'd expect LOADS of warnings or outright errors due to the lack of encryption and/or web servers not reacting well to the as of 1993 non-existent HTTP/1.1 requests your browser may send out

Comment: I suspect figuring out the handshake for wireless charging by trial and error would take longer than the phone's battery life.

Answer (score 28):

Forget apps.

### It can turn on the torch

The bright white LED is a miracle of science in 1993.

### It can take photos and videos

The digital camera is also sci fi in 1993.

### It may have some offline maps

Turns out you know what roads, stadiums, etc, are going to be built where. Maybe only in your part of Pennsylvania/Zagreb/Wellington, but still.

### It can play music and videos

Maybe someone has sent you a whatsapp video that you downloaded. Congrats, you have that video.

If you're really, really lucky, it has Ricky Martin or the Macarena or OK Computer and you have next year's biggest hit.
Failing that, there's still ringtones..

### It can store 64GB of data

I had to download DOOM (or was it Wolfenstein) over 4 successive nights on my dad's 4800 baud modem. The split zip files were 1MB each. I had to delete some other games. Too bad USB hasn't been invented yet.

Comment: Digital cameras _in phones_ weren't around until just before the millennium, but they were sold as separate machines in the late 80s.

Comment: In 1993, white LEDs weren't "miracle of science"-level.  Blue and trichromatic LEDs had been commercially available since 1989, although modern excited-phosphor white LEDs were still three years from commercial availability.

Comment: Right up until the battery dies... then there's no way to charge it. USB wasn't even invented until 1996 and the power protocol used by the iPhone 11 didn't exist until the 2000s.

Comment: @JBH Without internet, the battery last a week or so. Enough time to rig up an adaptor to charge it (albeit slowly, at 5V / 200mA max).

Comment: @Mark The high brightness GaN LED invented by Nichia was an order of magnitude brighter than the previous best. The 1990s series were little or no more efficient than incandescents. Yes, a GaN white LED in 1993 is a big deal.

Comment: @JBH If he has a cable (not a charger, just a cable), it's easy to put +5VDC across the two power wires. With no cable, he may be able to take the battery out.

Comment: @JBH 5VDC works for an iPhone, right? Or has Apple made that complicated too?

Comment: @Mark blue led were not available until at least 1999

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant yes 5V works. If you download the spec beforhand you can even solder some resistors across the data lines to get 5V/1A, which is pretty decent charging.

Comment: "It can store 64GB of data" - how are you going to get data onto the phone, or off of the phone? You can take 64GB back with you (and that can potentially net you billions of dollars, if you put the right things on there), but once you are in the past, accessing that storage is going to be a huge issue for a layperson.

Comment: @NotThatGuy, they'd get to photograph the documents off of the smartphone screen...

Comment: @camelccc Cree started selling blue SiC LEDs in late 1989. They were more cyan than deep blue, and not very bright, but they existed; I bought one in 1994 or so.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - Digital cameras in the late 80s were ridiculously pathetic compared to then-current film cameras, much less an iPhone 11.   (E.g., 640x480 resolution *max*, >$1000 pricetag, etc., etc.)

Comment: @EricBrown: Indeed.  Even the first digital camera I had in the 2000's was pretty crappy in terms of image quality.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant Now we're assuming that the person with the iPhone 11 knew anything about the battery, or the power requirements, or that such a person had the time, knowledge, or wherewithall to expose 20+ years of technology to the past. *It's just not that simple,* unless we ignore completely the narrative necessity of the story.

Comment: @JBH They may or may not know that a few volts of DC electricity charges the phone. That's up to the OP.

Comment: @JBH I did note that there was no USB in my answer, fwiw.

Comment: Forget apps?  Surely any apps that were already installed on the phone would continue to work (as well as they can work without Internet connectivity, anyway)

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant it is up to the OP... and the OP didn't include the skill, knowledge, or opportunity in the conditions of the quesiton. A lot of people answered this question based on assumptions not in evidence.

Comment: @JBH That's A-OK in my book, providing it's neither blindingly stupid nor precluded by the OP. If they like it, they can use it. If they don't, they won't. It's a suggestion, not an assumption.

Answer (score 18):

In the [history of mobile phones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mobile_phones), 1993 had GSM networks in Europe.

> In the 1990s, the 'second generation' mobile phone systems emerged. Two systems competed for supremacy in the global market: the European developed GSM standard and the U.S. developed CDMA standard. These differed from the previous generation by using digital instead of analog transmission, and also fast out-of-band phone-to-network signaling.

The iphone11 seems to be capable of [using GSM network](https://www.devicemag.com/how-to-tell-if-your-iphone-is-global-or-gsm/#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20the%20iPhone%2011%20model%20A2221%20is%20a,is%20used%20in%20most%20countries%20arond%20the%20world.)

> **Is the iPhone 11 a GSM Phone?**
>
> Yes, the iPhone 11 model A2221 is a GSM phone, also known as the Global Version. GSM stands for Global System for Mobile Communications and is a digital mobile network that allows users to make calls, send texts and access the internet. This type of network is used in most countries arond the world. The iPhone 11 model A2221 operates on GSM networks, meaning it will work with most cellular providers.

Therefore, maybe calls and SMS would be possible. However, the operator will need to recognize the SIM trying to access its services.

There will be no other working apps, I am afraid.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145463/discussion-on-answer-by-l-dutch-what-could-a-smart-phone-still-do-or-not-do-and); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 12):

1993 is not the Middle Ages and you could do a lot with such a phone provided you find people geeky enough. If you dropped by my university (in France) I could point you to a few people.

If you are yourself a techie you will make their life much easier but even without that they will find out.

Charging the phone is the easiest. You would either tell them about the voltage, or they would try slowly from 0V both ways and finally got the threshold.

Communicating with the phone is more difficult but doable. It would take time to reverse engineer, though. (EDIT: see @Abion74 comment below. As I mentioned, I was looking at my Android phone when replying and missed out thee iPhone part)

- There was no WiFi so bad luck here.
- Ethernet over USB is conceivable if Ethernet is present (it was rather the time of 10Base5, but at least the standard was in place - so who knows)
- Data transfer via USB would be fine

If you would consider upping the game by also bringing USB documentation with you, you would open the gates of sleepless nights for these guys and gals. It would be Christmas coming early for us.

You may also consider having an Android phone, which will be easier to work with.

Comment: _Breaking news: mankind shrinking technology over night_

Comment: without an original ucb cable - good luck

Comment: Charging/data transfer would only be realistically possible if OP brought a USB-to-Lightning cable with them. USB 2.0 would be a fairly doable challenge to reverse-engineer for a good techie in 1993 (power definitely, and data transfer might be doable with some difficulty), but the Lightning connector has an encryption and authentication module in the head of the plug so good luck getting your geeks to ever replicate that.

Comment: Trying to slowly ramp up the voltage would be a bad idea if the iPhone doesn't have a reverse-polarity protection diode (disclaimer: I know nothing whatsoever about iPhones).

Comment: @forest: yes, that's true - but short of a USB documentation or taking the phone apart (which would not be that useful - the lightening connector is molded in) there are no good solutions. Now, someone with electronics knowledge and a general knowledge of the intent of the connector could maybe work out the polarity (by analyzing responses) - but I fled my electronics courses so I do not know :)

Comment: @Abion47 - thanks for the note. I actually forgot that this was an iPhone (despite OP clearly indicating it) as I have ever only used Android phones and was looking at mine when replying. I will update my answer.

Comment: @forest I wager the negative on the USB port is connected to the negative on the battery which I wager has a black wire.

Comment: Showing up with a recent model Android in 1993 might put Apple out of business if you could sell the tech to the right people.  They were struggling before the first iPhone came out, which resulted in a huge resurgence in their popularity.  If you managed to scoop them by over a decade at that critical point in their history, it could have devastating effects on their already hurting business.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman If you started showing a modern Android phone around, you would expect to receive a call from Steve Jobs himself pretty quickly.

Comment: @Clockwork "Breaking news: mankind shrinking technology over night " <- Back in the early 90s, tech was already shrinking so quickly that there is very little you could do that would actually amaze people more than was already happening.  In fact, there were plenty of people who honestly believed that tech was only advancing as fast as it did because some alien or future tech had somehow been acquired, and movies like Terminator and Independence Day turned this into a common trope.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Now that you mention it, I remember seeing my parents' phone going from a flip phone the size of a gaming mouse, to the Nokia. Can't remember how much time has passed though.

Comment: Phones reached their smallest just a little before smartphones came in. Around 2005. I remember being surprised that the cool thing had gone from being small to features to being big.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman why would the OP want to sabotage their plan to buy massive amounts of Apple stock during its struggling period? (come on, everyone would. That and Bitcoin)

Comment: USB did not exist in 1993, so unless the time traveller bought the USB to Ethernet adapter with them then Ethernet over USB is a non-starter.

Comment: @PeterGreen: the USB cabling is simple so even without a proper connector you can have an artisanal plug that will bring in the cables.

Comment: Sure but "Ethernet over USB" isn't just ethernet with a different plug. "Ethernet over USB" means a host talking to a real or virtual Ethernet controller over USB. The plug is the least of your worries. You have both the whole USB protocol stack to contend with and then on top of that you have the interface for the virtual Ethernet controller.

Comment: @PeterGreen: it really depends on the documentation you have. yo will not be able to reverse engineer everything (especially Ethernet) but Ethernet drivers were already coded in 1993 (I patched one in 1994, my first coding in Linux) so there are no technological barriers, just know-how (which I agree is not a simple thing, thus my suggestion to bring USB docs)

Answer (score 9):

I don't think the other answer is correct.
the iphone supports GSM which was launched in 1991, so at least in metropolitan areas in Europe and asia it will be able to make emergency  voice calls. The united states did not adopt GSM until 1995 so this will not work here.
Making a charger out of stuff available in 1993 is trivial. 5v power supplies are easily available, and a knife and wires would be enough to physically connect the power pins. This is enough to charge at 0.5A.
Getting it to register to a gsm network of the time my be hard, unless you take a sim with a valid contract.
Although a sim of the time may be cut to fit, all sims at this time used 5v signaling, and I'd be surprised if the iphone supports this. Modern sims support 5, 3.3 and 1.8v.
Nevertheless, making electronics for this voltage shift is doable, though probably not fitting inside the sim slot.
Anything available in airplane mode will also work.

Comment: Looking at other answers, the phone will operate *as if* it were in flight mode. Calls, even to emergency services in the UK are not possible under flight mode. But as the iphone 11  supports GSM you think that it would be able to make an emergency call?

Comment: Can you clone an old SIM onto a new one?

Comment: Why does everybody seem to assume implicitly that all 'smart phones' are Apple products?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: OP specified in the question that it was an iPhone 11.

Comment: @Brian - OK. I missed that. I'm not a fanboy, as you may gather.

Comment: @AvengingEarth there is no reason it ahould not make emergency calls. Gettiing a sim to work will be hard, and as for gsm data suggeated in one of the answers forget it. gsm data is a data call, ro modem at the other end

Comment: GSM has changed over the years along with cell technology. The fact that the iPhone 11 supports GSM in 2023 does not mean it's compatible with GSM in 1993. Getting this phone to be recongnized on a 1993 cell network would indeed be miraculous.

Comment: @JBH gsm = what we call 2G. This original standatd is supported and this original standard is unchanged. You can still uae a 90s carphone. Read thw answer for the issues regarding getting a sim to work. Sims are backwards compatible with phones of the era. Old sims are not forwards compatible w 1.8v phones

Comment: Forget about the SIM - certificates/keys stored on it won't be recognized by the current networks.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 he could try a hail-mary, buy a credit-card-size SIM and cut it to Nano. From what I've read it could work but probably won't.

Comment: @Joooeey no he cant. All sims prior to 1998 use 5V signaling. All phones manufactured much after about 2000 use 3.3 or 1.8v signaling. 1,8V sims support 3.3 and 5V so will work in an old phone, but a 5V sim can't operate with a 1.8V supply. IF you can get around the 1.8V 5V issue, the protocol is I think the same, but this is a rather big ask. As for using the internal sim, Europe never supported this, and the USA didn't use GSM at all until 1995. this voltage conversion is going to be a pain since 1.8V logic chips came later, so you would have to build a circuit of transistors or something.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 cloning sims was hardly difficult then (or now), the but is you would need to clone onto a 1.8V sim and the hardware for doing that comes about 15 years later.  All you are finding in 1993 is 5V sims, and the iphone simply will not detect them even. At this point you are bringing rather more than the iphone, unless  you want to take the details of an old sim in a drawer, clone it onto a modern sim in the present time and then send him with the phone.

Comment: Without the tech specs for the charging port, or perhaps already being one of the rare engineers who knows that without having to look it up, it seems like someone setting out to build a charger would be more likely to destroy the phone than to reverse-engineer the tech for one.

Answer (score 8):

Who are you showing your phone to in 1993?

Suppose I worked for Sony. The had made the standard CRT video monitors for years. LCDs were not going to challenge them for dynamic range for another 15 years. If I were to see the display, I would want you to turn it off immediately. I would then arrange a microscope / spectrometer to get as much information as I could. You could tell me it was an OLED. I would know what an LED was, but the blue ones had not happened yet. We had not yet got to the point where CRTs would have rivals, but it would surely come. There was also a firm belief that semiconductor resolution was limited by the wavelength of near-visible light. But, once you are shown that the firm limits were not so firm, you can start thinking of alternatives.

When I was born, there were perhaps 48 Kbits of memory in the whole world, and 12 Kbits were in ENIAC. I remember clock speeds first going above 100 KHz, then 1 MHz. It is a huge leap of faith to make the first atom bomb, or the first hydrogen bomb. But when someone else has done it, and you know it is possible, figuring out how it might have been done is easier...

Comment: The iPhone 11 that the question specifies doesn’t have an OLED screen, it has an IPS LCD. The iPhone 11 Pro has OLED, but that’s not what we’re talking about.

Comment: Blue LEDs were invented in 1989, and available commercially in 1993.

Comment: and those guys at Sony would know very well that reverse engineering an integrated circuit like that isn't going to happen. They could get SOME information by taking x-ray photos of it, but that doesn't show the doping and other materials used.

Comment: Color LCD screens were already on the market in 1993.  The passive-matrix [Powerbook 165c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_160) came out Feb 1993 and the active-matrix [Powerbook 180c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerbook_180) came out in June 1993.  The backlights were electroluminescent.  They would not have been regarded as "magic" in 1993.

Comment: Yes, but they had a poor contrast ratio. We could not use them for film grading in 2010. The contrast ratio of an OLED screen would have beaten CRTs back then.

Comment: @jwenting There was a general belief that Moore's law was going to hit a hard limit when we got to the wavelength of light. Then UV. Then vacuum UV. Sony in my example could not have used this, but the chip makers would have noticed.

Comment: @Karl Blue LEDs were made from doped silicon carbide. They were not compatible with other LEDs, so you would have had to solder your display together.

Comment: @RichardKirk even if the chip makers would be able to deduce what photolithography process was used, the information is of little worth without the huge number of details one needs to get right to actually _implement_ such a process. Going to UV is a fairly obvious thing to do, but that doesn't mean it's easy.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I am not saying it is easy. It might even lead people up the wrong path, to use electron or proton beams instead of UV. But a large part of the increase in density was only possible by merging companies so they could afford the next generation plant. There were serious doubts that you could get beyond 1 micron, 0.5 micron, and so on, which made raising the money for the next plant ever more difficult.

Comment: But still it's very different from the nuclear weapon example you made. In the 1930s, it was completely speculative that even researching their design would lead to any useful results at all. (Rather like quantum computing or fusion power today.) By contrast, in 1993 is was completely beyond doubt that smaller chips would be a goldmine for any manufacturer who managed to build them. And much of the infrastructure and research committed in each architecture-shrink would have still been of some use, even if the concrete attempted process had ultimately turned out to not be commercially feasible.

Comment: @RichardKirk 1989 saw the invention of the blue GaN LED, Nobel prize 2014. The SiC version is older, but never worked really well. Was it even commercialised?

Comment: @RichardKirk I'm not talking about Moore's law, but about the inability to detect the actual material composition of a doped IC (or indeed any material) even through destructive means. Without the original product specifications you're going to be guessing. Which is what prompted the Israeli Mossad to steal the entire set of blueprints for the Mirage fighter jet (a massive and risky operation) rather than trying to reverse engineer one after France refused to honour their contract to deliver said jets that Israel had purchased.

Comment: The issue with reverse-engineering is that even if you can tell what's inside the phone and how it's all laid out, that doesn't really tell you what manufacturing process would allow this to be created. Those processes have changed dramatically over time, but the result is often just a smaller, more compact version of the same thing. If you take a microscope to a chip and see that it has smaller transistors than you are able to manufacture, that doesn't help much ─ "let's make smaller transistors" is not a revolutionary idea.

Comment: @kaya3 If you see layered memory chips, that's a very useful info. If you see small transistors, you can do the math and find out that extreme UV lithography will be possible. I'm sure modern touchscreens will be manufacturable with 1990 technology. Having a 2023 liion battery in your hands will give a lot of highly valueable information even if you don't have the process to make exactly the same electrode material. A patent for getting just half the 2023 capacity in 1995 will make you an instant billionaire.

Answer (score 8):

### Flip your phone to airplane mode.

Boom. You are in 1993.

By doing so, you just turned off the cellular data modem, WiFi and Bluetooth connectivity to other things, which are the key to everything that makes a phone *a phone* and not an iPod Touch, and none of which  exist in 1993.

Whatever still works on the phone, will work in 1993. You can (at the risk of this turning into "how to use a phone"):

- browse emails you already downloaded, but no new ones will come in
- use files that are locally downloaded on the device (cloud will be unavailable)
  — use apps like notes and calendar that are able to work offline despite being unable to sync.
- watch/listen to media in local phone storage, but not media "on the cloud"
- play games that don't need to bang a server for anything

You can give social media apps and always-connected games like Diablo or Pokemon:GO a try, but you'll find they complain about "no internet" and that's that.  If 10 of you brought your phones, Facebook and Tiktok will not work among you because the server infrastructure is not there.

The phone will not know what date it is, because the cellular data network and internet it gets the time from are not there. Speaking of that,

GPS will be extremely slow and less reliable, because phones use augmented GPS, which improves reach in complex geography and greatly speeds up GPS fixes, but reqires the cell towers be involved. Old GSM towers aren't set up for augmented GPS.  GPS on phones (and embedding that in 911/112 calls) is a long, long way off.

### Recharge

If you did not bring your charging block, the phone will deplete completely in 12-24 hours because every minute it is trying every generation of cellular it is capable of, notching up transmission power to max to try to reach a tower. If you have the foresight to switch to Airplane Mode almost immediately, you may get a week or two of standby time out of it, minus usage of course.

Supplying 5V to the port is simple enough, the problem is coming up with a workable substitute for the advanced USB-C or Tesla - I mean Lightning connector.

If you went to a competent lab and said "I know I can charge this by applying 5V to two pins of this heretofore undeveloped connector", they could probably X-ray it and figure out which pins from trace thickness and PCB markings.  Disassembling a modern phone non-destructively is a PITA unless you know the tricks.

5V or 3.3V would be an easy guess, since PCs of that age are already using that. Any PC power supply will give you the 5V. So you could eventually develop a charging cord that goes "PC keyboard port to Lightning" with a T-connector so the keyboard could still be connected.

At that point you would get basic boring USB charging at 0.5 to 2.5 watts.  No fast charge because no handshake.

### But GSM, though

Maybe you could make that work. But you'd only get talk and TXT, they aren't really doing data over GSM yet, but it doesn't really matter.  First, the system is not designed for the volume of data the phone would ordinarily use, and second, literally zero of the servers it would talk to are there yet.  Most likely the Internet connection would be saturated by the phone's ordinary housekeeping traffic, and the carrier would get mad and turn it off. Also, GSM takes unbelievable amounts of battery power compared to G5; they've been shrinking battery sizes accordingly and the result is much shorter runtime when on older networks.

Also, if you hadn't already installed a telnet/ssh app, you won't even be connecting to MELVYL or Compuserve, or a shell provider like Netcom or WELL. That was how you did the Internet then. Hope you enjoy command line lol.

Here's a twist, though: if you can get someone to support Internet data on GSM, **email will work**.  It should be able to talk to POP and SMTP servers of that age. Unbelievable. And that would be compatible with the constrictive data limits of GSM, since people weren't exactly mailing videos then.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are wrong about GPS. Augmented GPS is used to speed up GPS lock but if you want to get a lock without a cell phone connection / wifi connection to assist you, you just need to wait 5-15 minutes to get it.

Comment: NTS was around long before 1993.

Comment: I'm really curious now: What would it take to get GSM to work beyond emergency calls?

Comment: @Joooeey you will need a valid simcard of an active services provider. And I am not sure if simcards back then will be compatible with the current technology.

Comment: I think AGPS essentially uses the internet to download a file saying where the GPS satellites are today. It's not some passive listening thing. There *is* a passive listening thing though - the GPS satellites themselves are constantly broadcasting this data... very slowly. It takes 12.5 minutes to get a whole copy. 25 minutes if you missed some the first time, which is why we prefer to get it from the internet.

Comment: More than likely though you *don't* know that. At least I don't.

Comment: POP and SMTP are unchanged, but SSL/TLS certainly isn't; you'd be stuck with unencrypted connections, assuming the client supports them.

Comment: @Magnus good point, yes, you are correct - but the GPS signal will be barely usable by modern standards. Won't penetrate well into buildings or the artificial canyons known as "cities",  and will take a LONG time to establish a fix.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, "welcome to 1993" includes 1993 security lol.  I think *modern* SSL/TLS would have been a computing power problem for PCs and email servers back in that age, especially since so much stuff was server-bound. For instance I read my email by going 'telnet netcom.com' and sitting at their shell interacting with Pine or Elm. So netcom would bear the decrypt load, and that wouldn't scale.  Anyway what's the point? 'telnet' isn't encrypted so the surveiler now has my password.  Yes, barefoot, in the snow, uphill, *both ways*.. **and we liked it!** LOL

Comment: @freedom-m except the phone has a list of NTP servers. At least one will need to be up, and speak an NTP version and encryption level  the phone finds acceptable.  And even if phone time is successfully set, that may introduce glitches and bugs since Apple doesn't test its OS and apps for dates in the past... Y2K in reverse!

Answer (score 4):

To me, it sounds like you would pretty much have a pocket-sized fancy calculator/computer that can also play music and media stored on the phone, and has a working torch, a camera, a voice recorder, and can play games! It would impress the hell out of anyone encountering it. It would look (and be) superior to the Game Boy, the Walkman, Cd Players, portable TVs, etc.

But I don't think it would function as a phone as it would not be compatible with the networks of the time. Maybe if you took it to a research university and explained what it was, then maybe someone could figure out ways to make it work. But it's a big maybe.

Answer (score 4):

Also consider that if the phone can't find a cell to successfully connect to, it will turn up the transmit power and "yell harder" in case its just out of range.

The phone will use up the battery's store of power much quicker than normal.  If the phone lasts 24 hours of "normal" usage you might expect it to be flat in half that time.

This could be a plot point where the device turns off unexpectedly at a critical moment.

---

In airplane mode, the battery lasts a lot longer.  However the time-traveller would have to remember to change into this mode, and it may or may not allow GPS reception still.

Comment: In airplane mode, the battery lasts a lot longer.

Comment: @Karl Excellent point - added.

Comment: You can activate GPS separately, but it's also quite energy-hungry.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a major city, finding an electronic repair store like Radio Shack might be able to rig you up a rudimentary charger. They'd likely charge an arm and a leg, but it'd be doable; especially if you have a replaceable battery that lists its information.

Lucky for you, the full first constellation of GPS for the US military finished in 1993, and this is a send-only system. In other words, your phone would still pick up GPS (that said, government might have significant interest if they got whiff as you used it, because the first public use didn't come till later).

Between these two, you could get an instant job aboard any public seaship of the era.

Social media apps are *mostly* toast. Your only use from them will be some cached article headlines and messages. The former could be useful for knowing a handful of future events.

If you have local storage for your email, this could be a treasure trove of knowledge on the times of various major events, and guide predicting some things a bit more precisely than your memory.

Wireless calling:

1G and 2G actually existed in some cities at this time, but since your sim card is likely to an account that doesn't exist (and sim cards don't exist yet so you can't replace it). You'll be limited to 911 calls. This could be useful for emergency response, but that's about it. It could be a lifesaver though.

Cameras and Voice recorders of various kinds existed in this time, but they were big and bulky. Might be good for spy work since noone would expect.

The biggest benefit is going to happen if you're running Android and can get a Serial-to-serial connect juryrigged (doable, but a pain - again, a lot of time in radio shack - USB [Universal Serial Bus] is a descendant of older Serial Bus standards, and is surprisingly still backwards compatible - for example, I have a USB-to-Serial cable for my older printer - matchup could pretty much be figured out with a multimeter). Android is open source and Linux-based, and Linux already exists in this era, which means if you can get at the code, there may be chunks that could jump waaayyyy ahead in computer software development. Being closed source though, an iPhone will provide no benefit, as there's little to no chance that any of the code will be accessible. If the time traveller is a cell phone firmware developer, this will be the best bet to maximize use of the cellphone.

This last one is huge, because with that tech, because Linux relies on a small kernal that can still be installed on 90's computers today. You could crush Microsoft & Apple and prevent the rise of Google. The OS code syntaxes would reveal ARM architecture, so you could also overpower AMD and Intel. Now, they won't be able to replicate the chips themselves, because modern boards use chemical pressing techniques that weren't nearly as precise back then - that march of time will still have to repeat because that precision came from better computers & sensors which allowed better precision tools which allowed better computers & sensors, etc, and the sensors on a cellphone aren't nearly the quality used for production & develoment. (Though your phone's processing capabilities may be able to bump them forward a few years - or a lot of other industries for that matter - it's basically a handheld supercomputer for the time).

Answer (score 2):

## At first you won't be able to read any emails. But with some work you could read everyone's

The iphone 11 comfortably outclasses the largest supercomputer of the era, at about 6 times faster (690GFlops, vs 100Gflops). In addition, the NSA had mandated a relatively low strength encryption standard (DES 56), which would later be trivially cracked. You can break into pretty much anything. Of course, you'd need to be decent at computing, but once you're there, the world is pretty much your oyster. Try and make sure you download the wikipedia article on the dotcom bubble before you go.

Answer (score 1):

What you couldn't do

**Charge the phone**
The USB standard hasn't been invented yet so you can't charge it via micro-USB or USB-C

**Transfer files to the phone**
The phone either connects via USB or by reading the micro-sd card (if it has one). Neither of those exist in '93.

**Call someone**
The operators in '93 wouldn't be able to recognize the standard the SIM card in your phone uses.

**Access the internet**
Both mobile data or wifi and both are non-existant at this time in history.

Comment: Charging would be much easier with a different brand of phone. Foe example, many modern Android phones still have a removable battery, so you can use any laboratory power supply with an amperage limit to charge it.

Comment: @vsz every battery is removable if you have a screwdriver and soldering iron

Comment: Although the micro-SD form factor didn't exist in 1993, you can trivially create a electrical connector with pogo-pins and talk to in using the SPI protocol, which dates from the 1970s. You'd then have to work out what commands to send via the protocol, but it would be doable.

Comment: also lithium batteries were rarer in 1993, but still around. I'm sure any laboratory would have no problem getting their hands on a suitable charger.

Comment: @user253751 : or you charge the battery manually, with a current-limited power supply, and carefully monitor it yourself, disconnecting it before it goes too close to 4.2 Volts. That should be possible even with common laboratory equipment from over a hundred years ago.

Comment: The problem though: Would you know how to "properly" charge a Lithium battery in 1993? The exact voltage ratings should be specified in product data sheets, but you wouldn't have that at this point in time.

Comment: @Coreus :  I removed my battery from an old phone, and the most important characteristics are printed right onto the battery.  Or just forget about the battery, remove it, and connect the lab power supply directly to the battery contacts of the phone.

Comment: @vsz This wildly depends on the phone. Many modern phones cannot have their batteries removed very easily, risking breaking the phone in the process.

Comment: Just open the phone up and sell the chip set and you would make technology jump 20 years in 5 to 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without testing but the Lightning connector (wiring of that can be found [here](https://www.etechnophiles.com/lightning-connector-port-pinout/)) has one pin for power (pin 5) and another for the ground (pin 1). Unless Apple has done something to require the digital communication, a good laboratory of the time may be able to make a custom connector to charge device. It is not that miniature:

[image]

I think that a good laboratory of 1993 should be capable of making this connector ([image credit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lightning_connector_03.jpg)). This can be done, for instance, by etching the narrow printed circuit board (technology appeared in about 1956). Mind that only two contact plates need to be drawn to implement the charger, not all 8.

Being able to charge opens more scenarios for prolonged usage, unless you need a tension for your story with the battery running out.

Comment: The connector is not needed if you dismantle the phone and solder to the wiring inside. Or if the time traveller luckily brought a Lightning cable with them (not necessarily a charging cable)

Comment: @user253751 The problem is, a user unfamiliar with all the iFixIt.com tricks required to get into a phone, is all but guaranteed to smash the glass trying.  That's the digitizer, so game over. Far safer course would be to X-ray it and look at the PCB. If there's no handshake and just +5V on the port, the phone should charge at a limited speed.